# Ruby block implicit variables

Tags: ruby, lambda, block

I wonder if Ruby has something like implicit block parameters or wildcards as in Scala that can be bound and used in further execution like this:

```
my_collection.each { puts _ }
```

or

```
my_collection.each { puts }
```

There's something like symbol to proc that invokes some method on each element from collection like: `array_of_strings.each &:downcase`, but I don't want to execute object's method in a loop, but execute some function with this object as a parameter:

```
my_collection.each { my_method(_) }
```

instead of:

```
my_collection.each { |f| my_method(f) }
```

Is there any way to do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do it with:

```
my_collection.each &method(:my_method)
```

`method` is a method defined on Object class returning an instance of `Method` class. `Method` instance, similarly to symbols, defines `to_proc` method, so it can be used with unary `&` operator. This operator takes a proc or any object defining `to_proc` method and turns it into a block which is then passed to a method. So if you have a method defined like:

```
def my_method(a,b)
  puts "#{b}: #{a}"
end
```

You can write:

```
[1,2,3,4].each.with_index &:method(:my_method)
```

Which will translate to:

```
[1,2,3,4].each.with_index do |a,b|
  puts "#{b}: #{a}"
end
```

Comment: To avoid `& interpreted as argument prefix` warning add parenthesis around `&method` like `my_collection.each(&method(:my_method))`